# How many ways are their to recite vedas?

Tags: vedas

I read somewhere that you can recite vedas in 11 different way.

So how many ways are there to recite vedas. Can you give some video examples of those ways?

---

<sup>I read about 11 different way in this cite as a comment or          [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/45097/22556).</sup>

Comment: You read it here! https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/45097/21353

Comment: @Proxy thanks for the help 

Comment: See this: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLiNK-KgBCVJA7xVUCyryykhjwkC44gVd0